# Image Upload to rackspace cloud files using PHP

Tags: php, winapi, rackspace

I am trying to upload file to rackspace cloud file using the following code:

Upload.html

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    File: 
    <input name="upload" type="file" /> 
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload To Rackspace!" />
</form>
```

Upload.php

```
<?php

// include the API
require('cloudfiles.php');

// cloud info
$username = ""; // username
$key = ""; // api key

// Connect to Rackspace
$auth = new CF_Authentication($username, $key);
$auth->authenticate();
$conn = new CF_Connection($auth);

// Get the container we want to use
$container = $conn->get_container('resumetune');

// store file information
$localfile = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
$filename  = $_FILES['upload']['name'];

// upload file to Rackspace
$object = $container->create_object($filename);
$object->load_from_filename($localfile);

?>
```

Now i am getting the gollowing error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'BadContentTypeException' with message 'Required Content-Type not set' in C:\xampp\htdocs\rackspace\cloudfiles.php:1645 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\rackspace\cloudfiles.php(1962): CF_Object->_guess_content_type('C:\xampp\tmp\ph...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\rackspace\upload.php(24): CF_Object->load_from_filename('C:\xampp\tmp\ph...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\rackspace\cloudfiles.php on line 1645

So any one have any idea about this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looking at http://github.com/rackspace/php-cloudfiles/blob/master/cloudfiles.php at the function _guess_content_type() it's looking for the Content-type and it's not finding it.  Either you need to add more information to your /share/magic or you can probably set the Content-type before calling the load_from_filename if you know what the content type is.

Comment: thanks, i got that.. just after posting the questions. anyway thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here's a fix if you have neither mime or FileInfo functions available:

```
function _guess_content_type($handle) {

    $ext = ".".end(explode(".", $handle));
    switch($ext)
    {
        case 'jpg': $this->content_type = "image/jpeg"; break;
        case 'gif': $this->content_type = "image/gif"; break;
        case 'png': $this->content_type = "image/png"; break;
        default: $this->content_type = "image/jpeg"; break;
    }

    if ($this->content_type)
        return;

    if (function_exists("finfo_open")) {
        $local_magic = dirname(__FILE__) . "/share/magic";
        $finfo = @finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME, $local_magic);

        if (!$finfo) 
            $finfo = @finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);

        if ($finfo) {

            if (is_file((string)$handle))
                $ct = @finfo_file($finfo, $handle);
            else 
                $ct = @finfo_buffer($finfo, $handle);

            /* PHP 5.3 fileinfo display extra information like
               charset so we remove everything after the ; since
               we are not into that stuff */
            if ($ct) {
                $extra_content_type_info = strpos($ct, "; ");
                if ($extra_content_type_info)
                    $ct = substr($ct, 0, $extra_content_type_info);
            }

            if ($ct && $ct != 'application/octet-stream')
                $this->content_type = $ct;

            @finfo_close($finfo);
        }
    }

    if (!$this->content_type && (string)is_file($handle) && function_exists("mime_content_type")) {
        $this->content_type = mime_content_type($handle);
    }

    if (!$this->content_type) {
        throw new BadContentTypeException("Required Content-Type not set");
    }
    return True;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have the FileInfo extension enabled (enabled by default since PHP 5.30). I suggest you check if mime_content_type() function is available.

It seems that if you have neither of those, the Content-Type cannot be detected. If neither is available right now, i'd get [FileInfo](http://pecl.php.net/package/Fileinfo)

Answer (score 0):

I found Chris Bake's solution helpful.  I needed to put a "." in front of each extension below.

```
$ext = ".".end(explode(".", $handle));
switch($ext)
{
    case '.jpg': $this->content_type = "image/jpeg"; break;
    case '.gif': $this->content_type = "image/gif"; break;
    case '.png': $this->content_type = "image/png"; break;
    default: $this->content_type = "image/jpeg"; break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider using the newer official [Rackspace PHP SDK](http://docs.rackspace.com/sdks/guide/content/php.html). Here's the sample code for [creating an object](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/blob/master/samples/objectstore/createobj.php).